# A python script subprocess in Java does not get destroyed when running in Windows

Tags: java, python, windows, process, processbuilder

I am writing a console Java application that spawns a subprocess containing a long running Python script. When the Java application terminates, I call the `process.destroy()` method to terminate this python process. However, the process is still visible in the Task Manager even though the parent Java process terminates.

Another thing to note is that the python process destroys successfully when the same code is run in Linux.

I have tried calling `process.destroyForcibly()` as well, but that doesn't work either. I read in the javadoc that `destroyForcibly()` calls `destroy()` by default.

The process is spawned by calling the following method in main():

```
public static Process executeNonBlockingPython(List<String> args, String workingDirectory) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if(taggerProperties== null || taggerProperties.isEmpty())   init();
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        if(workingDirectory != null && !workingDirectory.isEmpty())
            processBuilder.directory(new File(workingDirectory));

        // Prepare the command to be executed based on the base operating system.
        if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("win")) {
            command.addAll(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            new String[] {
                                        "cmd.exe",
                                        "/c",
                                        taggerProperties.getProperty("PYTHON_EXECUTABLE")
                                    }
                            )
                    );  
            command.addAll(args);

        }
        else {
            command.add(taggerProperties.getProperty("PYTHON_EXECUTABLE"));
            command.addAll(args);
        }
        logger.debug("Executing python command: "+command.toString());
        // Spawn the process
        processBuilder.command(command);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = null;
        process = processBuilder.start();
        return process;
    }
```

Here `args` is a list of arguments that are to be passed to the python script. This method will then prepare the list of arguments for executing the process and pass it to the `processBuilder.command()` method. Finally it will return the process object for handling the process after the method ends. The property `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` is the absolute path to the Python.exe file. Is there anything I am missing here?

The python script itself, runs in an infinite loop, reading files from a directory (passed in the argument), processes them and writes them to another directory.

Comment: According to java docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html you should be calling process.waitFor() after you call process.destroy() or you can chain it together process.destroyForcibly().waitFor()

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but it seems clear that if you use `cmd.exe /c path\to\python.exe`, then `destroy()` will just terminate the shell and not the child Python process. Run python.exe directly instead.

Comment: If you need to use cmd.exe for some reason (e.g. for the convenience of command line pipes and I/O redirection), it is possible to kill CMD and its child processes with additional work. (1) cmd.exe can be added to a terminate-on-close Job object that doesn't allow child process breakaway. Or (2) if your process is attached to the same console, create the cmd.exe process with the flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, in which case send the group Ctrl+Break via `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` to kill child console processes that are attached to your console (not a new console, GUI, or detached).

Comment: Wow, that was actually the issue. The shell terminated but the Python process did not. I was under the impression that destroying cmd.exe would also destroy it's child process. After some tests, I have concluded that I don't require to run python through the shell, at least for my use case right now, so I removed the cmd command from the process arguments and the python process gets destroyed as expected now. Thanks for the heads up @eryksun. If you reply with the answer, I will mark it as solution.